# Lead function in Hive

Tags: hive, lead

I am trying to retrieve the next "name1" after a specific "name2". For example, next "name1" after "complete2" in "name2" is "init3". This is the query I use, but it returns null.

```
    date_time                    name1        name2           
    2017-11-23 00:09:46          init1        complete1
    2017-11-23 00:09:48          init2        complete2
    2017-11-23 00:09:50          init3        complete3


   select date_time,name1,name2,
   lead(name1,1) over (order by date_time) as next_word
   from tab1
   where date_time between "2017-11-23 00:00:00" and "2017-11-23 23:59:59" 
   and name2 like "%complete2%";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT date_time,name1,name2,
               LEAD(name1,1) over (ORDER BY date_time) AS next_word
          FROM tab1
         WHERE date_time between "2017-11-23 00:00:00" and "2017-11-23 23:59:59" ) v
 WHERE name2 LIKE "%complete2%";
```

Output

```
2017-11-23 00:09:48 init2   complete2   init3
```

Hive evaluates the WHERE conditions before applying the LEAD. In your query that would have limited the LEAD to be applied in one record for which there was no LEAD.

You can use a subquery like I have done above or use a CTE/ WITH Clause.

Hope this helps!